# Insert space in between string Regecp Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle11gr2

I have some addresses not in proper format. I want to add a space if there is none. Example shown below

```
Input          Expected output
-----          ----------------
AVEX           AVE X or AVENUE X
AVE  X         AVE X or AVENUE X
AVENUEX        AVENUE X or AVE X
AVENUE   X     AVENUE X or AVE X
AVEOFCITY      AVE OF CITY  or AVENUE OF CITY
```

I created a below expression ,but it is not giving correct result for all cases, especially the AVENUE breaks into AVE NUE

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('AVENUEN','^(AVE(NUE)*?)(\w)','\1 \3') rep FROM dual;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get you a little closer.  Just tweaked your regex a little to allow for an optional 'NUE' and handle 0 or more spaces after.

```
with tbl(id, str) as (
  select 1, 'AVEX'       from dual union all
  select 2, 'AVE  X'     from dual union all
  select 3, 'AVENUEX'    from dual union all
  select 4, 'AVENUE   X' from dual union all
  select 5, 'AVEOFCITY'  from dual
)
SELECT
  id,
  REGEXP_REPLACE(str,'^(AVE(NUE)?) *?(\w)','\1 \3') rep 
FROM tbl;
```

You may need another pass to handle the 'OFCITY' as who knows what could come after the AVENUE that you have to allow for.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It is much better now!As of now I am only handling AVE OF followed by any string. Will try to accomplish that. Thanks again Sir!